# Running Exec() on Remote Server

Tags: php

Can I use PHP `exec()` to run a terminal command on a remote server? If not, what can I use and how? I need to execute a terminal command on a remote server. What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ssh2_exec()`](http://php.net/ssh2_exec) instead. And very obviously you need permission (= an account) on the remote server and an enabled SSH service. It's quite a standard option for Unix/BSD/Linux servers.

If you don't have that extension installed, then using `ssh` via exec() is the next best thing (but requires some setup, you need keys rather than password authorization):

```
 print exec("ssh user@server 'ls -l'");
```

Comment: Additional information. The command i am going to execute is going to run a C++ binary on the remote server, make some computations and write a file somewhere on that server. How can I pull that file from that remote server?

Comment: You can use `ssh2_scp_recv)` or `exec("scp ...")` for copying afterwards.